# SAS running out of memory when trying to do fuzzy matching using hash tables on a small sample dataset

Tags: indexing, sas, hashtable, large-data, fuzzy-comparison

I have a list of names, phone numbers, and addresses with ~5,000,000 rows. I am trying to create a list of unique customers at each address with each unique customer being assigned a key. The customer names are not formatted consistently, so John Smith might appear as, e.g., Smith, John, or John Smith Jr., etc.

The logic I want to follow is this:

If two records *at an address* have the same phone number, it's the same customer, whether they have different names or not, and get assigned the same customer_key.

If two records *at an address* don't have the same phone number (or have no phone number), but a fuzzy match on their names exceeds some threshold, they are the same customer, and get assigned the same customer_key.

Note that the same customer name + phone number match at two separate addresses should *not* be assigned the same customer key.

Here are example tables containing sample input and desired output:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsABSFy5a5dLE8mC-ZQF_lNg4I0kLQy7dEFhbfovq40/edit?usp=sharing

My code attempt using this sample dataset is below:

```
data customer_keys(keep=customer_name customer_key customer_phone clean_address);
   length customer_name $50 Comp_Name $20 customer_key 8 clean_address comp_address $5 customer_phone comp_phone $11.;

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash h(multidata:'Y');
      h.defineKey('Comp_Name','comp_address');
      h.defineData('Comp_Name', 'customer_key','comp_address', 'comp_phone');
      h.defineDone();
      declare hiter hi('h');

      declare hash hh(multidata:'Y');
      hh.defineKey('customer_key');
      hh.defineData('customer_key', 'Comp_Name','comp_address','comp_phone');
      hh.defineDone(); 

      _customer_key=0; 
   end;

   set testdat;

   rc=h.find(key:customer_name, key:clean_address);

   if rc ne 0 then do;
      rc=hi.first();
      do while (rc=0);
         if not missing(customer_phone) and clean_address=comp_address and customer_phone=comp_phone
            then do;
                  h.add(key:customer_name,key:clean_address, data:customer_name, data:customer_key, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);
                  hh.add();
            end;
         else if not missing(customer_name) and clean_address=comp_address and jaroT(customer_name,Comp_name) ge 0.8
            then do;
            rc=hh.find();

            do while (r ne 0);

               dist2=jaroT(customer_name,Comp_name);
               hh.has_next(result:r);

               if r=0 & dist2 ge 0.8 then do;
                  h.add(key:customer_name,key:clean_address, data:customer_name, data:customer_key, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);
                  hh.add();
                  output;return;
               end;

               else if r ne 0 & dist2 ge 0.8
                then rc=hh.find_next();

               else if dist2 < 0.8
            then leave;

            end;

         end;

         rc=hi.next();

      end;

      _customer_key+1;
      customer_key=_customer_key;
      h.add(key:customer_name,key:clean_address, data:customer_name, data:customer_key, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);
      hh.add(key:customer_key, data:customer_key, data:customer_name, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);
   end;

   output;
run;
```

Running this code yields the error:

```
ERROR: Hash object added 23068656 items when memory failure occurred.
FATAL: Insufficient memory to execute DATA step program. Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.
ERROR: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient memory.
```

I notice that if I remove the additional logic dealing with the phone number entirely, I don't have this memory issue. However I am still going to assume that my approach will fail either way because of lack of memory when I try to run it on the full dataset.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a recursion error.  The dataset is only a handful of rows so there's no way you'd run out of memory without some kind of recursion happening.  Try dumping the contents of `h` and `hh` after 1 iteration of the loop, after 2 iterations of the loop etc. You'll probably see straight away where it's going wrong.

Comment: @RobertPenridge I believe that you are probably right, since the output file on memory error is 23,000,000 rows. Can you tell me how to push out the contents of h and hh after n iterations? I see that I can use the method 

h.output(dataset:'dataset'); 

But not sure how or where to use it.

Answer (score 1):

search for "sas.exe-memsize 16G" in your windows search function to pull a new version of sas program that will have 16G in memory storage. You can change the number before G, too. Also make sure you have enough disk space. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably need to do this once I am sure that there isn't an error causing unexpected behavior in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the memory issue and now the code is working as expected! The error was in the section dealing with matching phone numbers. The corrected code is below:

```
data test customer_keys(keep=customer_name customer_key customer_phone clean_address);
   length customer_name $50 Comp_Name $20 customer_key 8 clean_address comp_address $22 customer_phone comp_phone $14.;

   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash h(multidata:'Y');
      h.defineKey('Comp_Name','comp_address');
      h.defineData('Comp_Name', 'customer_key','comp_address', 'comp_phone');
      h.defineDone();
      declare hiter hi('h');

      declare hash hh(multidata:'Y');
      hh.defineKey('customer_key');
      hh.defineData('customer_key', 'Comp_Name','comp_address','comp_phone');
      hh.defineDone(); 

      _customer_key=0; 
   end;

   set testdat;

   rc=h.find(key:customer_name, key:clean_address);

   if rc ne 0 then do;
      rc=hi.first();
      do while (rc=0);

         if not missing(customer_phone) and clean_address=comp_address and customer_phone=comp_phone
            then do;
            rc=hh.find();

            do while (r ne 0);

               hh.has_next(result:r);

               if r=0 then do;
                  h.add(key:customer_name,key:clean_address, data:customer_name, data:customer_key, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);
                  hh.add();
                  output;return;
               end;


            else leave;

            end;

         end;


         if not missing(customer_name) and clean_address=comp_address and jaroT(customer_name,Comp_name) ge 0.8
            then do;
            rc=hh.find();

            do while (r ne 0);

               dist2=jaroT(customer_name,Comp_name);
               hh.has_next(result:r);

               if r=0 & dist2 ge 0.8 then do;
                  h.add(key:customer_name,key:clean_address, data:customer_name, data:customer_key, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);
                  hh.add();
                  output;return;
               end;

               else if r ne 0 & dist2 ge 0.8
                then rc=hh.find_next();

               else if dist2 < 0.8
            then leave;

            end;

         end;


         rc=hi.next();

      end;

      _customer_key+1;
      customer_key=_customer_key;
      h.add(key:customer_name,key:clean_address, data:customer_name, data:customer_key, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);
      hh.add(key:customer_key, data:customer_key, data:customer_name, data:clean_address, data:customer_phone);

   end;

   output;
run;
```

Also below I am posting the code for the jaroT function so that others can use it if they'd like, I didn't write this function, and you could substitute it in my code above with any comparison algorithm you'd like (be sure to also change the threshold numbers):

```
FUNCTION jaroT(string_1 $,string_2 $);

if STRING_1=STRING_2 THEN return(1);
else do;
length1=length(string_1);
if length1>26 then length1=26;
length2=length(string_2);
if length2>26 then length2=26;
range=(int(max(length1,length2)/2)-1);
big=max(length1,length2);
short=min(length1,length2);
array String1{26} $ 1 _temporary_;
array String2{26} $ 1 _temporary_;
array String1Match{26} $ 1 _temporary_;
array String2Match{26} $ 1 _temporary_;

/*The following two do loops place the characters into arrays labelled string1 and string2. 
While we are here, we also set a second array of the same dimensions full of zeros.  This will
act as our match key, whereby values in the same relative position as those in the original string
will be set to 1 when we find a valid match candidate later on.*/

do i=1 to length1 by 1;
    String1{i}=substr(string_1,i,1);
    String1Match{i}='0';
end;

do i=1 to length2 by 1;
    String2{i}=substr(string_2,i,1);
    String2Match{i}='0';
end;

/*We introduce m, which will keep track of the number of matches */

m=0;

/*We set a loop to compare one string with the other.  We only need to loop the same number of
times as there are characters in one of our strings.  Hence "do while i<=length1".

We set the allowable search range for a character using pos and endpos, and set another loop to
search through this range.  We loop through until we find our first match, or until we hit
the end of our search range.  If the character in string 2 is already signed to a match, we move
on to searching the next character.  When we find a match, the match flag for that character in both
strings is set to 1.  Hopefully by the end of the loop, we have match flags for our two arrays set.

*/

do i=1 to length1 by 1;
pos=max(i-range,1);
endpos=min(range+i,length2);
    do while (pos<=endpos and String1Match{i}^='1');
    if String1{i}=String2{pos} and String2Match{pos}^='1' then do;
        m=m+1;
        String1Match{i}='1';
        String2Match{pos}='1';
        end;
    pos=pos+1;
    end;
end;

/* If there are no matching characters, we do not bother with any more work, and say the two strings are not alike at all */

IF m=0 then return(0);

else if m=1 then do;
t=0;
end;

/* If those three conditions all fail, then we move onto the heavy lifting.*/

else do;

/* We set i back to 1, ready for another looping run.  

c is a variable to track the position of the next valid transposition check.
j is a variable helping to keep track of matching characters found during the next loop inside string 1.
k is a variable helping to keep track of matching characters found during the next loop inside string 2.
t will be the number of tranpositions found.

*/

i=1;
c=1;
k=0;
j=0;
t=0;

/* We begin our loop.  These conditional loops within loops 
make several logical conclusions to arrive at the correct number of transpositions and matching characters 
at the beginning of a string.  At the end of this we should have every variable we need to calculate the winkler
score (and theoretically the jaro as well).  I'm not going to write out an explanation here, but if you're
interested all the extra variables are defined just above this comment, and I've already told you what the
string arrays are.  Work through a couple of examples with pen and paper, or in your head, to see how 
and why it works.*/

do while (j<m OR k<m);
    IF j<m then do;
        IF String1Match{i}='1' THEN DO;
            j=j+1;
            String1{j}=String1{i};
        end;
    end;
    IF k<m then do;
        IF String2Match{i}='1' THEN DO;
            k=k+1;
            String2{k}=String2{i};
        end;
    end;
    IF j>=c and k>=c then do;
        IF String1{c}^=String2{c} then t=t+1; 
    c=c+1;
    end;
i=i+1;
end;
end;

/* Finally, we do the calculation of the scores */

jaro=(1/3)*((m/length1)+(m/length2)+((m-(t/2))/m));

return(jaro);
end;

endsub;

FUNCTION fuzznum(num_1,num_2,diff,direction);
IF direction=-1 THEN DO;
    IF num_1-num_2<=diff AND num_1-num_2>=0 THEN RETURN(1);
    ELSE RETURN(0);
    END;
IF direction=1 THEN DO;
    IF num_1-num_2>=-(diff) AND num_1-num_2<=0 THEN RETURN(1);
    ELSE RETURN(0);
    END;
IF direction=0 THEN DO;
    IF ABS(num_1-num_2)<=diff THEN RETURN(1);
    ELSE RETURN(0);
    END;
endsub;
```